Swashbuckle.AspNetCore ProblemDetails can't be generated as Swagger Schema
Does someone know what I do wrong?
Or if this is really a bug by Swashbuckle.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2944
BR, Sandro
